# Docker — Unable to access pgsql inside container in Laravel app

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a Laravel app using docker. As database, I want to use pgsql. But I am able to connect pgsql connection from outside to localhost but when I try to connect it from inside the container by setting env variables, it shows below error when I try to run migrations,

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here is my docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: gdd/laravel
    container_name: myapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: myapp
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - mynet

  nginx:
    container_name: lara-nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - mynet

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: app
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

#Docker Networks
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-source delete \

COPY . /var/www/html

COPY ./.env /var/www/html/.env

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

EXPOSE 80 443
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=172.20.0.3
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

site.conf for nginx:

```
server {
  server_name myapp.test;
  listen 80;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/html/public/;

  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your env file is in the same directory as compose file

You need to put the database container in the mynet  network

Use Docker service names, not IPs - `DB_HOST=db`

Make sure you are actually reading `env['DB_HOST']` in the code. As your error shows, it got `127.0.0.1`, not the actual value you've set